# Npm install rally coding eslint in atom is not working

Tags: react-native, atom-editor, eslint

I've installed linter and linter-eslint plugin in atom. But installing eslint rallycoding is giving trouble. What might be the issue, I can not figure it out.

Following is the error message:

```
E:\zreactNative\test\ReduxTest>npm install --save-dev eslint-config-rallycoding
npm WARN deprecated eslint-plugin-class-property@1.1.0: please use eslint-plugin-babel and babel/semi
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...2.0","esutils":"^2.0.'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\bbeck\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-25T07_13_26_749Z-debug.log
```

[2018-09-25T07_13_26_749Z-debug.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tudvESKMHwiCBLw6zXiSpcnDngbD55Z8)

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ReduxTest",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.2.0",
    "jest": "23.5.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. It was an issue of npm. npm cache clean --force does the trick.